# Extend the basis of subspace $U$ to the basis $M_{2 \times 2}^{\mathbb R}$ by adding vectors from the standard basis of $M_{2 \times 2}^{\mathbb R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

> Extend the basis of subspace $U$ to the basis $M_{2 \times 2}^{\mathbb R}$ by adding vectors from the standard basis of $M_{2 \times 2}^{\mathbb R}$. The basis of $U$ is $B_U=\{\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\4&1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&3\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}\}$.

Could I say that the problem is equivalent to finding the subspace $T$ such that  $M_{2 \times 2}^{\mathbb R}=U \oplus T$?

Comment: No, you cannot. There are infinitely many such subspaces. Besides, what has finding such a subspace to do with the standard basis?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos So should I just add 2 vectors ${e_3,e_4}$ to $U$ where $e_3=\{0,0,1,0\}$, $e_4=\{0,0,0,1\}$?

Comment: Something like that, except that those things are not elements of $M_{2\times2}^{\mathbb R}$.

Comment: Right in the matrix form.

Comment: But this is exactly what would've happened if I found $U\oplus T$ though. Because I'd need to show that $M_{2 \times 2}^{\mathbb R}=U+T \Rightarrow U+T=Sp\{U \cup T\}=Sp\{B_u,e_3,e_4\}$ and that $dimT=2$